# Run a jar file in cmd while compiled inside a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, jar

I have a jar file that is compiled inside my java program and it runs without any error when my java program is not compiled as a runnable jar file. Now, when I try to run my runnable jar file my program doesn't work. How can i access a jar file compiled inside a jar file?

Here's the code:

```
javaFile = "c:\\users\\jakeryan\\desktop\\javaCodeProgram.java";
javaFileTempRes= "c:\\users\\jakeryan\\desktop\\result.txt";

Process process = runtime.exec("cmd /c java -jar checkstyle-8.2-all.jar -c /google_checks.xml -f plain -o " + javaFileTempRes + " " + javaFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, you do NOT want to open a java.io.File ressource that points to a jar file from within the started jar file. But you want to start a shell cmd that uses this jar file. This has nothing to do with the running java program so you have to unzip and then use the jar file as standard from within the shell cmd.

Answer (score 0):

The standard class loader in Java cannot understand jars inside jars.  This will not work.    You can, however, extract the jar to a temporary location and refer to it there instead.

Consider adding your overall goal to your question.  There might be a better approach to what you want to do, depending on the context you have.